# Problems connecting to SFTP with R and RCurl

Tags: r, sftp, rcurl

I am attempting to connect to an SFTP site to pull data. It used to work, but for some reason, it stopped working a couple of weeks ago. The owners of the SFTP say nothing has changed on their end, and I can pull data easily without error using WinSCP.

```
protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "sftp.xxxx.net"
userpwd <- "user:password"
file <- "/public/bpus_dailytx.csv"
url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, file)
data <- getURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd, verbose = TRUE)
```

When I run this, I now get the following info:

```
*   Trying xxx.xx.xx.xxx...
* Connected to sftp.xxxx.net (xxx.xx.xx.xxx) port 22 (#0)
* SSH MD5 fingerprint: 34rh3ie93hhr39hhdik3
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,keyboard-interactive
* Using SSH public key file '(nil)'
* Using SSH private key file ''
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to extract public key from private key file: Unable to open private key file
* No identity would match
* Authentication failure
* Closing connection 0
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Authentication failure
```

It connects OK but then the authentication fails. Any ideas what could be going on here? Again, this code used to work but something has changed. What are some other ways I can attempt to pull the data other than this?

Edit: WinSCP screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you ever had a public/private key pair for this website?

Comment: Yes, we use a public/private key pair with a passphrase. I can connect with WinSCP using the passphrase just fine, and it USED to work in R

Comment: Could you please provide screenshots of your WinSCP setup - specifically the Login window (with necessary redactions) and the Authentication page under Advanced Site Settings?

Comment: You are not passing the private key anywhere and since you said it logins with the SSH key, i believe you need to pass that

Comment: Does the following work: `data <- getURL(url = url, keypasswd = "your_key_passwd", ssh.private.keyfile = "your_path_to_keyfile", username = "your_user_name")`?

Comment: @MatthewSchuelke Adding screenshots of WinSCP now

Comment: That also did not work. Also, probably related, when I try to open up the public key, I get the following message: Couldn't load the key (SSH-2 public key (RFC 4716 format))

Comment: What is the format of your key ? isn't it a putty format  and not an SSH format ? If so open it with puttygen to export it as opensshKey (in the converstions menu)

Comment: Or just copy your key under `%HOME%\.ssh\` anming it `id_rsa` which is the default place searched by openssh libs.

Comment: The Open SSH key worked!! Thanks for everything guys. If someone creates an answer I will give you the bounty.

Comment: Still funny to me that my old solution stopped working. But, this other method works just fine.

Comment: Did you copy and rename the keyfile like @Tensibai suggested?

Comment: @MatthewSchuelke no, I converted the private_key.ppk to Open SSH and used that.

Comment: @Stu with my code example?

Comment: @MatthewSchuelke yes, I used your code sample, and just pointed it to the new Open SSH Key and it worked like magic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to say why your code stopped working because we do not have enough information about configurations (both on your machine and on the server) when it was working.

Because your keyfile was not in the proper format for RCurl, my leading hypothesis is that although the server folks said nothing changed on their end, I think they removed the password authentication option. That is because your code attempts password authentication only. If password authentication were still available, the one line in your output would look something like this:

`SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive`

It is, as you noted, now:

`SSH authentication methods available: publickey,keyboard-interactive`

Therefore, the solution here was to convert your keyfile from PuTTY to OpenSSH format using PuTTYgen and then use the following RCurl code pointing to your new keyfile:

```
protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "sftp.xxxx.net"
file <- "/public/bpus_dailytx.csv"
url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, file)

keypasswd <- "your_keypasswd"
ssh.private.keyfile = "your_path_to_keyfile"
username <- "your_username"

data <- getURL(url = url, keypasswd = keypasswd, ssh.private.keyfile = ssh.private.keyfile, username = username, verbose = TRUE)
```

And I will add a special thanks to @Tensibai for the assistance. It would have taken me way longer to arrive at this solution without their insight with the keyfile format.